# If for loop fails does counter still go up?

Tags: c#, for-loop

If `doStuff()` throws exception do I need `i--;` in a catch block to try it again?

```
          for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
          {
               doStuff();
          }
```

Comment: by fails, do you mean it throws an exception?

Comment: So, wrap it in a try/catch block and in your catch block just do `i--`, just note that if it continues to fail, your loop will never end.

Comment: if it fails at any point and you call `doStuff()` again, wont it just fail again

Comment: @MattBurland That's precisely my question, I do need i-- ?

Comment: Should be easy enough to test. Just force `doStuff` to throw an exception and watch.

Comment: @Ric No, it's a query that times out every once in a while, not often though.

Comment: @user2525463: What's precisely your question? That makes no sense. If `doStuff()` threw an exception, it will probably require you to change something for it to not throw again. But without knowing what `doStuff` is, how is anybody supposed to tell you?

Comment: So sort the timeout issue

Comment: @user2525463 Maybe increase the timeout instead.

Comment: @MattBurland Didn't ask how to fix doStuff() there is more than enough info to answer my actual question. Thanks Sam I am

Comment: I have to agree with @MattBurland, you are obviously having trouble with `doStuff()` but the solution you have come up with to run the function until it works, and that you are asking us for help about, is not a good solution. You should try to fix/ask about the _actual_ problem instead.

Comment: @user2525463 Matt is correct.  Handling an exception in your `for` loop is only masking a bigger problem in your code.  Don't do this.  Fix the issue in `doStuff()` then you will not have to catch exceptions in your loop.n  Don't be lazy.

Comment: @EvanL I appreciate your concern and I'm not being sarcastic, but I asked a question about the increment of a loop. As for as doStuff() it's a request to a remote server that I have no control over and it causes issues sometimes.

Comment: @user2525463 Of course there are going to be methods that throw exceptions.  Exceptions wouldn't be in the language otherwise.  However, we have no idea if you should catch the exception, or if you should decrement the loop counter.  That's a business decision for your application.  You may want to keep going, you may want to retry until it works, you may want to retry a fixed number of times, you may want to let the exception bubble up out of the loop, you may want to do something else.  All of those can be valid in certain circumstances, and without knowing the circumstances we can't answer.

Comment: @user2525463 No problem, I see that that issue has been addressed and I understand your question was pointed at the loop, it just seems like a "patch" rather than a "fix".  And patches can be leaky ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you've posted, if an exception is thrown, it will exit your `for` loop altogether and resume from where the highest level `catch` block is.

If you wrap it in try/catch, `i` will still go up by 1.

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    try
    {
        doStuff();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the exception.
        //i-- does not count as handling the exception.
    }
}
```

as a note, I'd avoid adding `i--` in your catch block, because you're probably going to end up with an infinite loop that throws an exception forever.

Answer (score 2):

In short:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    try 
    {
        doStuff();
    }
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

This will retry `doStuff` for the same index until it completes without throwing. The `i--` is needed because after the catch we go around the loop again, and the `for` statement will execute `i++` just before we restart, so we need to cancel that out.

However, this is probably a bad idea because what if `doStuff` is hitting some condition that makes it throw forever?

(Also, in this example I catch the `Exception` base class. This means it will catch `NullReferenceException`, which is almost certainly not what you want, for reasons too gnarly to go into.)

Comment: Could this cause a potential `StackOverflowException` if the method keeps failing and the index keeps decrementing?

Comment: No. No extra nested method calls are made, which is the only way that could happen.

Comment: @Ric only if `doStuff` is recursive, but in that case, it woudl be throwing the SO exception anyway

Comment: Fair enough, thought I'd ask and learn something new! Cheers guys.

Comment: @Ric It would however (potentially) run forever, which is in certain contexts actually *worse*.

Comment: @Servy That's why I thought the `SO` exception would occur if it's running forever, but thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If the DoStuff is not in a try catch block than i will not go up but you will exit the for scope i will be garbage collected and your application will crash for unhandled exception.
If you are in a try block than the for loop doesnt care about the exception since its some of the code functionality and i will up.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't just loop indefinitely like this, I would instead at least include some kind of out if `doStuff()` keeps failing. Perhaps something like this:

```
int maxRetries = 10;
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    try 
    {
        doStuff(); 
    }
    catch (Exception)    // Note: you really should catch the most specific exception you expect doStuff to throw
    {
        if (maxRetries > 0) 
        {
            // Do anything you need to do to make the call more likely to work next time
            maxRetries--;
            i--;
        }
        else
        {
            // give up - return a message to the user that something is wrong
        }
    }
}
```